# How to link an excel file with the application software using Java swing

Tags: excel, java

I have to link an excel file with a application software which I am developing.The excel file will contain questionnaire for conducting surveys.I have this code which is only able to open a Jpanel to select the file.After I select the file nothing is happening.I wanted to be able to generate a template based on the questions that are in the excel file (like extracting the questions from the excel file and creating a template from it) and which I have to upload on the web later.could you please help me with this?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;


public class SelectFile extends JFrame{


    public static void main(String[]args){
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setLayout(null);

                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setTitle("Select File for Linking");
                    frame.setSize(400, 100);
                    Container container = frame.getContentPane();
                    container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

                    final JTextField text=new JTextField(20);

                    JButton b=new JButton("Select File");
                    text.setBounds(20,20,120,20);
                    b.setBounds(150,20,80,20);

                   // b.setText("<html><font color='blue'><u>Select File</u></font></html>");
                    b.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
                    //b.setBorderPainted(false);
                    //b.setOpaque(false);
                   // b.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                                fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new OnlyExt());

                                int returnval = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                                if (returnval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                                text.setText(file.getPath());
                                } 
                            }
                    });
                    container.add(text);
                    container.add(b);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
            }
    }
        class OnlyExt extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter{
            public boolean accept(File file) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) return false;
        String name = file.getName().toLowerCase();
        return (name.endsWith(".xls"));
        }
        public String getDescription() { return "Excel ( *.xls)"; }
        }
```

Comment: Of course nothign is happening, you only select the file name but you sem not to do anything with the file. Your question is completely unclear anyway, what do you mean with "link the excel file to your application"?? Do you want to start Excel and let it open the file? Do you want to talk to Excel to do something with the file?

Comment: @Angel O'Sphere  +1 good question.  I was prepared to jump to some conclusions, but I'd still be interested to hear the answer.

Comment: By "Linking an excel file" means that the excel file will contains questionnaire for surveys.I have to read these questionnaire using the software that I am developing and have to store it in database.After that I have to develop a template based on these questions from the database and have to upload this template on web.So I am unable to do these parts of the software i.e. reading,storing in database and then creating template

Answer (score 1):

Apache POI http://poi.apache.org/ provides an API for reading / writing Excel Files.

Answer (score 1):

Look over this source for some tips.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class SelectFile {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Select File for Linking");
                // don't use null layouts.
                //frame.setLayout(null);

                // create a panel so we can add a border
                JPanel container = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(3));
                container.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
                frame.setContentPane(container);

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                // instead call pack() after components are added
                //frame.setSize(400, 100);

                final JTextField text=new JTextField(20);

                JButton b=new JButton("Select File");

                // irrelevant unless button stretched by layout
                //b.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
                b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                        String desc = "Excel ( *.xls)";
                        String[] types = {".xls"};
                        fc.addChoosableFileFilter(
                            new FileNameExtensionFilter(desc, types));

                        int returnval = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                        if (returnval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                            text.setText(file.getPath());
                            try {
                                // 1.6+
                                Desktop.getDesktop().edit(file);
                            } catch(Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                container.add(text);
                container.add(b);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

BTW - The `JFrame` here would probably be better converted to a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane`.

Comment: I don't believe, I don't believe, that there still exists +1